# I want to make the button goes to a new page when last radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, html

Watch live code
http://jsfiddle.net/fo3660xe/

Code fully and upon another option I can change the text before redirect can be different from the rest of the text-button can be added and hide all the pages and shown only on the last page that immediately prior to redirect

```
 <p class="text" id="first_one">
 <span>لقد تم دعوتك للدخول فى تحدى مع احد ابطالنا</span>

 <span class='poll'>
 <span>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" checked/>
 <label for="radio1">1</label>
 </span>

 <span>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio"/>
 <label for="radio2">1</label>
 </span>

 <span> 
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" class="radio"/>
 <label for="radio3">1</label>
 </span>

  <span>    
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" class="radio"/>
  <label for="radio4">1</label>
  </span>
  </span>

  <br/><br/>
  </p>





 <p class="text" id="first_one">
 <span>لقد تم دعوتك للدخول فى تحدى مع احد ابطالنا</span>

 <span class='poll'>
 <span>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="radio" checked/>
 <label for="radio1">1</label>
 </span>

 <span>
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio"/>
 <label for="radio2">1</label>
 </span>

 <span> 
 <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" class="radio"/>
 <label for="radio3">1</label>
 </span>

  <span>    
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio4" class="radio"/>
  <label for="radio4">1</label>
  </span>
  </span>

  <br/><br/>
  </p>
```

and  jquery

```
$("#slider1next").click(function() {
var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next('p');
$next.length ? $next.show() : window.location.replace('start.html');
```

});

Comment: you want a message after the test is completed? right?

Comment: ask your question clearly?

Comment: Code fully and upon another option I can change the text before redirect can be different from the rest of the text-button can be added and hide all the pages and shown only on the last page that immediately prior to redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your jquery with this.

```
 $("#slider1next").click(function() {
        var $next = $(".text:visible").hide().next('p');
        $next.length ? $next.show() : window.location.replace('http://jsfiddle.net/');

    });
```

Comment: @YallaNsatrae try this one...

Comment: Code fully and upon another option I can change the text before redirect can be different from the rest of the text-button can be added and hide all the pages and shown only on the last page that immediately prior to redirect

Comment: do you want to change which text?

Comment: -       <button id="slider1next" >next</button>    -    change  next